# How to determine request (URL) that iPhone app sends to server?

Tags: iphone, url, networking

I am trying to find out the structure of request (URL, POST or XML file) that a particular iPhone app sends to server to retrieve data from it.

In the browser you always see the URL that was used to retrieve HTML of the page, but in the iPhone app you don't see the URL it uses. You only see the server's response visualized by the app. So, how can I find out the request that an app used to retrieve the data from server?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Think could be a useful tool: http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Answer (score 1):

Use a [packet sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) like [Kismet](http://www.kismetwireless.net/) or Kismac to view the traffic on your home wifi network.

Comment: is it the only way? This approach seems not so easy taking into account the number of different requests that go through my home wifi...

Comment: Run the test when there is no other traffic on your wifi...also you can usually dump the logs somewhere and search for what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Charles proxy for that.

http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Start Charles in your computer
Then change iPhones proxy settings to use Charles proxy.

To use this, your computer and iPhone should connect to the same wifi network.